# Text is not showing on website in Chrome for mac

Tags: html, css, wordpress, macos, google-chrome

The text on a Wordpress website I'm working on is not showing in Chrome for mac, until I resize the window or show the developer tools. The problem is not consistent either; sometimes it shows the paragraphs but not the headings.

The problem has arisen at some point during the development and I'm not sure when.

Two screenshots of the issue (before and after):
[screenshot1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2159914/insidefitness_issue/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-10%20at%2011.14.58%20.png)
[screenshot 2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2159914/insidefitness_issue/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-10%20at%2011.15.05%20.png)

URL: insidefitness.dk

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I can replicate the issue. Most likely the "Ubuntu" webfont is not ready when your css is fired.

EDIT:

**Solution**

include this in your main.css:

```
body
{
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix{
    from{   opacity: 1; }
    to{ opacity: 1; }
}
```

As it turned out this is a Chrome issue:

[Issue 336476:  External Font not rendering until forced repaint](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476#c34)

Comment: Thanks for the input. It doesn't seem to solve the problem though. I'm  fiddling around with different ways to load the fonts and hope to find a solution.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you copied/pasted/saved the code into your `head` section and before your main.css stylesheet?

Comment: yes. I can see that the code in the head section overrides the css, but it still doesn't show the heading.

Comment: I see it's loaded after the main.css stylesheet. Did you also try placing before the main scripts and links?

Comment: I have now placed it in the very top of the head section, but it still doesn't work. Do you have any other suggestions?
Thanks for your effort btw.

Comment: Try adding `font-weight:normal;` And also you don't need to use `!important` when this piece of code is before the main.css.

Comment: hmmm... when I remove '!important' the code is overridden by main.css.  so main.css is still loaded before?

Comment: Most likely it's been overridden by using Javascript. Is this theme bought from somewhere, and if so, do they provide support?

Comment: I found a solution to the problem on the support page for the theme. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: There is a [bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476#c34) with loading external fonts, which is the reason to the problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Was this the solution that worked for you? If not, it would be great if you could provide an answer.

Comment: Yes. That was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your console > network. It looks like your css is fired but the fonts haven't loaded yet. Could you try making sure you have the fonts before you load the css?

The following setup should work, this is different then yours because you load the fonts in your css file.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
        font-size: 48px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. It doesn't seem to solve the problem though. I'm fiddling around with different ways to load the fonts and hope to find a solution.